# Python: how to have mutually exclusive groups in subparser using argparse?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, mutual-exclusion

I am writing a program like:

```
import argparse

def task1(args):
    print "running task 1"

def task2(args):
    print "running task 2"


if __name__=="__main__":
    parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="How can I have mutually exclusive groups in subparsers?")
    subparsers=parser.add_subparsers()
    t1sub=subparsers.add_parser("task1")
    #....
    t1sub.set_defaults(func=task1)
    # here I would like to have a mutually exclusive group
    # when task 1 of the option one between --in and --out is required, but one excludes the other
    # apparently a subparser has no add_group() not add_mutually_exclusive_group(), though
    t2sub=subparsers.add_parser("task2")
    #....
    t1sub.set_defaults(func=task2)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    args.func(args)
```

As explained when I run task1 one between `--in` or `--out` is required but not both. 
How can I add this functionality to my program??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subparsers support all the methods a normal parser supports, including `add_mutually_exclusive_group()`:

```
>>> megroup = t1sub.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
>>> megroup.add_argument('--in', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--in'], dest='in', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> megroup.add_argument('--out', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['--out'], dest='out', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['task1', '--in'])
Namespace(func=<function task1 at 0x10a0d9050>, in=True, out=False)
>>> t1sub.print_help()
usage:  task1 [-h] [--in | --out]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --in
  --out
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] {task1,task2} ...

How can I have mutually exclusive groups in subparsers?

positional arguments:
  {task1,task2}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
```

Comment: I am sorry, but what is the role of _SetAction? (thanks for the answer in any case, I am trying to make it work).
Also, do you know how in func1 I could import only the value of the parameters of the p1sub parser (+ the main parser one) and not of the p2sub parser?

Comment: `_SetAction`? Do you man `_StoreTrueAction` perhaps? It's the return value of the `add_argument()` calls, echoed by the Python interpreter.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *'import only the value of the parameters of the p1sub parser'*. The `parser.parse_args()` function only returns the values for the parameters for the matched sub parser.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry I didn't notice it was an output.
Ok just the last question, maybe you can help me.. can you change the value of func depending on the --in --out flag? internally I would like to have a f1_in(args) and a f1_out(args)..
I am trying your solutions, and will vote for it if it works.. I have tried to use subparsers and mutually excusively groups, but it didn't work, maybe I was using the wrong syntax..

Comment: @LucaCerone: just set `func` to another function when `--in` or `--out` is set: `.add_argument('--in', action='store_const', dest='func', const=f1_in)` would store the `f1_in` function into the `func` attribute of the namespace if selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this actually helped me a lot. I am sorry if the questions are trivial, I find the official documentation a bit hard to digest..